# Write speed to SharePoint

Tags: performance

How fast can we write binary data to SharePoint? For example, could we define SharePoint write speed as a percentage of raw SQL write speed in terms of writing raw binary files on disk. SharePoint writes to a document library, SQL writes to a table. How much does the SharePoint overhead (stored procedures etc) slow down the write time (in percentage)?

Comment: The other question compares server-side vs client-side write speeds, while this question compares SharePoint write speed to SQL write speed

Comment: Gotcha, ignore that then. Will have to look into tests done in the past and see if I can find what you need :)